# 403 permission error in YII

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I have transferred my YII website from old domain to the new domain, I am changing in my host file to check the changes reflected.
My problem is that YII throwing 403 permission error if I am not using slash(/) after the URL but if I put slash (/) after the site name all working perfectly.

Working setting

```
ipaddress http://example.com/
```

Not working setting

```
ipaddress http://example.com
```

How i will able to remove that permission error without using slash(/) in hostfile setting. I have also tried it by using .htaccess file,  it throw 500 internal server error, when using htaccess file

Comment: What hostfile are you talking about?

Comment: window's host file

Comment: The correct format is `ip example.com` - not `http://` needed there as that has nothing to do with the hostname.

Comment: I have added both for this. With http:// and without http://

Comment: the site works only when i use index.php in the url

Comment: No, your hosts file must only have one entry for the hostname (the domain name). Then, you manage http/https configuration with your HTTP server (Apache, I assume). So you need to have a virtual host configured that will serve the content. For us to help, you'll need to share your virtual host config and htaccess file.

Comment: I have asked help with my server provider for this and they have solve it with change in the permission and changes in the htaccess code